# Magento category filter - The attribute model is not defined

Tags: magento, layered-navigation

I can't solve the following problem:

When I make a category anchor the category filter produces the following error:

```
The attribute model is not defined

Trace:
#0 /home/users/showiftp/mysite.com/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Layer/Filter/Abstract.php(239): Mage::throwException('Het attribuut m...')
#1 /home/users/showiftp/mysite.com/app/design/frontend/default/galastreetstyle/template/colorselectorplus/state.phtml(9): Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Abstract->getAttributeModel()
#2 /home/users/showiftp/mysite.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home/users/sho...')
#3 /home/users/showiftp/mysite.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/defaul...')
#4 /home/users/showiftp/mysite.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#5 /home/users/showiftp/mysite.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#6 /home/users/showiftp/mysite.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#7 /home/users/showiftp/mysite.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('layer_state', true)
#8 /home/users/showiftp/mysite.com/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Layer/View.php(177): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('layer_state')
#9 /home/users/showiftp/mysite.com/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/layer/view.phtml(40): Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer_View->getStateHtml()
#10 /home/users/showiftp/mysite.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home/users/sho...')
#11 /home/users/showiftp/mysite.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/base/d...')
#12 /home/users/showiftp/mysite.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#13 /home/users/showiftp/mysite.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#14 /home/users/showiftp/mysite.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#15 /home/users/showiftp/mysite.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
#16 /home/users/showiftp/mysite.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#17 /home/users/showiftp/mysite.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('left', true)
#18 /home/users/showiftp/mysite.com/app/design/frontend/default/galastreetstyle/template/page/2columns-left_store-details.phtml(89): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('left')
#19 /home/users/showiftp/mysite.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home/users/sho...')
#20 /home/users/showiftp/mysite.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/defaul...')
#21 /home/users/showiftp/mysite.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#22 /home/users/showiftp/mysite.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#23 /home/users/showiftp/mysite.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#24 /home/users/showiftp/mysite.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#25 /home/users/showiftp/mysite.com/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/controllers/CategoryController.php(161): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#26 /home/users/showiftp/mysite.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Catalog_CategoryController->viewAction()
#27 /home/users/showiftp/mysite.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('view')
#28 /home/users/showiftp/mysite.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#29 /home/users/showiftp/mysite.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#30 /home/users/showiftp/mysite.com/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#31 /home/users/showiftp/mysite.com/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#32 {main}
```

I can still reach the category by entering the nice URL but all links ending with ?cat= break like this...

Hope anyone knows how to solve this.

Fritz

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?